# How echo the month which is use bye GROUP BY cluas in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date

```
  $sql="SELECT `Variant`, COUNT(`Variant`) AS tsold, `sold_date` FROM `vehicle_sold` GROUP BY MONTH(`sold_date`), `Variant` ";  

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo  $row["Variant"],"--want to show month here---",$row["tsold"],"<br/>";

  }
```

The result it shows is correct like:

```
GLI A/T-- month?---1
GLI A/T-- month?---1
XLI M/T-- month?---1
GLI A/T-- month?---2
GLI M/T-- month?---2
Grande-- month?---1
XLI M/T-- month?---2
GLI A/T-- month?---2
GLI M/T-- month?---6
XLI M/T-- month?---3
GLI A/T-- month?---1
GLI M/T-- month?---4
Grande-- month?---1
GLI A/T-- month?---1
```

I want it show like:

```
GLI A/T-- January---1
GLI A/T-- FEB---1
XLI M/T-- FEB---1
GLI A/T-- March---2
GLI M/T-- March---2
Grande-- March---1
XLI M/T-- April---2
GLI A/T-- April---2
GLI M/T-- May---6
XLI M/T-- Jun---3
GLI A/T-- Jun---1
GLI M/T-- July---4
Grande-- July---1
GLI A/T-- July---1
```

Comment: have you tried to select `MONTH(`sold_date`) as month_sold_date` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MONTHNAME` in following:

```
SELECT `Variant`, COUNT(`Variant`) AS tsold, MONTHNAME(sold_date) AS mname FROM `vehicle_sold` GROUP BY MONTH(`sold_date`), `Variant`
```

Comment: @NasirHussain If that worked for you, do not forget to accept It as correct answer for future users. Check `V` in top-left corner of answer.

Comment: I was wondering if you help me further, now again i have problem actually i have to pass this data to javascript MONTH array and to tell how much time each vehicle has been sold out in each month.

Comment: This is other question. Accept this and ask new question with details about problem.